# What do I set "Folder:" to in Windows 10 Map Network Drive to access my Macbook Pro's hard disk?

Tags: windows, networking, macbook

What do I set the folder to with Map Network Drive so that my Windows 10 can access files and folders on my Macbook Pro?

I've enabled Macbook's Prefs > File Sharing and it showed the IP to use.  I've tried the following, but Windows pops up `The specified network password is not correct`:

Windows > File Explorer > Map Network Drive > Folder: `\\<MacIP>\<my admin account>`

Answer (score 0):

I got it working perfectly by following [How to share Mac OS X Yosemite files with Windows 10](https://www.itworld.com/article/2844141/how-to-share-mac-os-x-yosemite-files-with-windows-10.html)

Comment: Please... Do not post link-only answers. Links become invalid over time. Include the steps required in your answer. You're not a real newbie on this site. You should know this by now.

Comment: To build on @Tonny's comment, if you only want to post a link, please do so as a comment.